# Load CSS BG Image before showing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS background image that is not small and unfortunately I have compressed it as much as possible in Photoshop. I have a loading div that hides the page from displaying until the page is loaded. However it will show the div before the CSS BG is loaded. How do I keep the script from firing until the CSS BG Image is loaded?

***CSS:***

```
#background-wrap{
   background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   /* Cover for IE 7/8 */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
   -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
   /* End Cover for IE 7/8 */
   background-size: cover;
   background-color: transparent !important;
   position:fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
   max-width:3000px;
   max-height:1500px;
   z-index:1;   
    }
```

***HTML:***

```
<div id="loading">
<h2 class="textcenter">Loading...</h2>
<img id="loading-image" style="width:32px;" class="center" src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
<div id="content-wrap" class="hide">
<div id="background-wrap">
    <div class="img-center" style="z-index:9999;"><img  src="img.png" />
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

***JS:***

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   $j(window).load(function() {
        $j('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $j("#content-wrap").fadeIn("slow");
    });
 });
```

Comment: May I ask WHY the background image needs to load before the actual content? Usually the content is more important.

Comment: @Blazemonger - I have a page where the BG image is apart of the main content. I am doing this as an easy way to have a full screen image that scales to the users screen size without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done to pre-load the background (thought maybe not the best solution) was to insert the image I am using as a background into the html code as so:

```
  <div id="img-load" class="hide">
    <img src="path.jpg" />
  </div>
<!-- Rest of Page Code -->
```

The use the following script:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   $j(window).load(function() {
        $j('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $j("#content-wrap").fadeIn("slow");
   }); 
});
```

(Note: `.hide` = `style="display:none;"`)

This method seems to work without issue.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS**

```
#background-wrap {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(["path/bg.jpg"]).preload();
$('#background-wrap').fadeIn('slow');
$.fn.preload = function () {
  this.each(function () {
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
  });
}
```

Comment: With that code I see this error: `

TypeError: $j(["img-path.jpg"]).preload is not a function` I am using jQuery 1.8.1 if that matters (?)

Answer (score 1):

You can preload the image via JavaScript, and then wait to the load event to add the image src to the `DIV#background-wrap`. Also you will need to remove all references to `bg.jpg` in the CSS.

```js
// Creates an empty image
var $img = $('<img>'),
    src = 'bg.jpg';
// Adds a listener to the image on load event
$img.load( function(e)
{
    $('#background-wrap').css('background-image', 'url('+src+')')
    .css('filter', "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+src+"', sizingMethod='scale')")
    .css('-ms-filter', "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+src+"', sizingMethod='scale')")
    .fadeIn('slow');
});
// (pre)load the image
$img.attr('src', src);
```

Or you can use the jQuery plugin [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) to preload one or more images:

```js
var src = 'bg.jpg';
$('<img>').attr('src', src).imagesLoaded( function( $images, $proper, $broken )
{   
    $('#background-wrap').css('background-image', 'url('+src+')')
    .css('filter', "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+src+"', sizingMethod='scale')")
    .css('-ms-filter', "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+src+"', sizingMethod='scale')")
    .fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin which is the part of masonry plugin:

https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/jquery.masonry.js#L390-446